# Erro getting query from linked server

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I am trying to get a query in sql from linked server in Mysql but I am getting an error that I do not know.
Query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([ATP_PROD],
      'SELECT id FROM ta-transactions.transactions_status')
```

I got this error:

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ATP_PROD" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.38]

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'-transactions.transactions_status' at line 2".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 5

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You need backticks around the database name if it contains special characters like `-`.

Comment: ```'SELECT id FROM `ta-transactions`.transactions_status'```